# How can I protect a 12 V, 5 A circuit from high current due to short circuit condition?

Tags: circuit-protection, fuses, over-current

How can I protect a 12 V, 5 A circuit against high current due to short circuit?

I have tried resettable fuses but they do not work as expected. I have tried MF-USML300/12-2. In actual application (with PWM based MOSFET control and a resistive load,) the fuse sinks around 5.2 A current overall and trips.

Expected behavior: The fuse must not trip when the device operates at around the maximum value of the adapter i.e. 5 A. If a condition occurs due to circuit/adapter fault and the current increases, the fuse must trip immediately.

Comment: What will your power supply do if the current exceeds 5A?

Comment: It will drop the voltage and source current keeping the power constant. There is however a maximum limit to which this can safely happen before the adapter is damaged.

Comment: Are you saying you need something that will trip at some *exact* current between 5.0A and 5.2A?

Comment: If the current exceeds 5 A, the Fuse must trip to protect both circuit and the adapter. The Fuse MF-USML300/12-2 has a trip current of 6 A. So I expected the device should have operated normally because the current never exceeded 6 A.

Comment: E-fuses exists for this very reason.

Comment: What kind of an adapter? The best solution may well be getting one that has current protection (typically "hiccup" mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the datasheet, MF-USML300/12, has a hold current of 3 A, and a trip current of 6 A. What that means to me is the fuse is designed to operate at 3 A and is guaranteed to trip above 6 A. What happens in between is undefined, but tripping at 5.2 A doesn't seem unreasonable. This is because fuses aren't hard limits, where they immediately trip above a given current, rather they have a function of time to trip versus current; as current increases, time decreases exponentially. See this graph for some lite fuse blade fuses.

[image: Graph of time to trip vs current]

*Fig 1, graph from ATOF® BLADE FUSE RATED 32V data sheet. [Link](https://docs.rs-online.com/fe92/0900766b8128f542.pdf)*

You see it's nonlinear. If you need a 5 A operating current, then the MF-USML550/12 has a 5 A holding current. If you need a more aggressive function, or I mean to say you need something that will break the circuit very quickly above 5A, you'll either need to look for a different part or consider designing some kind of current monitoring.

I notice in your comment you mention that the PSU itself limits to 5A, and will limit the voltage, so what extra protection is a fusing system going to give you?

It is worth mentioning while on the subject that part of the reason you might want to allow a very temporary overcurrent is transient behavior. If you really had a breaker that blew at 5.001 A immediately, and your system was operating at 5 A, then any brief transient might break the circuit unnecessarily. If you have some capacitance on the power supply, it's actually very easy to generate a bit more current when your PSU attempts to limit the voltage. Your PSU supplies 5 A, and your capacitor which is discharging from 5 V to 4.X V supplies a bit more. Particularly in a circuit with switched MOSFETs your transient currents might be quite varied.

Answer (score 2):

> The fuse must not trip when the device operates at around the max value of the adapter i.e. 5 A. If a condition occurs due to circuit/adapter fault and the current increases, the fuse must trip immediately.

You can't expect such behaviour with a PTC resettable fuse, or at least with the one you selected.

Trip current is not the only parameter when selecting a resettable PTC fuse. You should also consider the hold current as well. Because, the current flowing through the PTC heats it up, so the trip point will be lower due to the heat *(Note that the hold current is defined as the maximum continuous current that allows the PTC to operate without tripping for at least 4 hours.)*. Likewise, if the environment is hotter then the trip point will be lower than that given for room temperature.

The PTC fuse you are using has a trip current rating of 6A, and a hold current rating of 3A, both at room temperature (23 °C). Now if the continuous current is 5A then it'll push the PTC and help it to trip easier, because of the heat generated by the current (or basically, dissipation of the PTC).

Another thing is the reaction time. It's given as 5 seconds maximum for trip point. This is, of course, far from "immediately" requirement.

What I can suggest here is to design a discrete circuit that involves shunt resistor and amplifier/comparator, and a latch (if latched protection is required).

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of off the shelf devices that can do this.

Consider using a circuit breaker. These have a metallic strip, which has properties not unlike your resettable fuse. But they also have a magnetic tripping action, the function of which is to cut the power very fast when there is an extreme overload condition like a dead short.

Example: [GMCB-1B-5](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/circuit_protection_-z-_fuses_-z-_disconnects/circuit_breakers_-a-_circuit_protectors/miniature_supplementary_protectors/gmcb-1b-5)

Keep in mind that even these require approximately 4x the rated current to trip instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself what you're trying to protect.

If the power supply already has output short circuit protection, it doesn't need any further protection. Pretty much all good quality switching supplies do, so that shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to protect a thin wire connected to a power supply that is powerful enough to overheat the wire and start a fire, a fuse is adequate.

> PWM based MOSFET control and a resistive load

If you want to protect your MOSFET... by electronics standards, fuses and circuit breakers are pretty slow, and usually semiconductors will blow before these protections have time to act.

If the power supply limits the current, and the supply capacitors aren't too large, then the MOSFET doesn't need extra protection. However a short on the load will cause the power supply to drop to zero and the whole board will stop working, which may not be what you want.

So I'm kinda guessing what you want is to keep the device functional if there is a load short, and perhaps display an error.

In this case the protection must be faster than the power supply's overcurrent protection, and if there are large capacitors on the supply it should also act before the MOSFET pops while it soaks all the energy stored in the caps through the shorted loads.

If you're using the standard common source PWM MOSFET design, the solution is to put a current source resistor between the MOSFET source and ground. Then, a comparator monitors voltage on this sense resistor, and when it goes over a threshold, it stops the PWM. This can be done with a RS flop, or other flop, or sometimes microcontrollers have special features in their PWM peripherals that allow for this.

Using a comparator gives good accuracy, so the protection will trigger before the supply goes into current limit, and your board will still work.